# Rewrite using .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess

I want to rewrite a url

"http://www.example.com/folder1/index.php/commonfuntion/about" to "http://www.example.com/about.html".

I tried the following code in the htaccess file which is in folder1:-

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule about.html$  /folder1/index.php/commonfuntion/about [L]
```

However I didn't get the desired result. How to complete the task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code may fix your issue

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com/folder1/index.php/commonfuntion/about$ [OR]
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/about.html$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your rule in the document root, folder1's parent folder. Because the URL you're attempting to go to, `http://www.example.com/about.html` isn't inside folder1.

Also, don't forget to turn the rewrite engine on:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule about.html$ /folder1/index.php/commonfuntion/about [L]
```